# Finding elasticsearch _score

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch. I have 24000 documents. I know how to find the match() and _score of each output document against the search query for top n queries. But my requirement is to find '_score' between a query string and a known document(record), which does not appear in top records in elasticsearch.

Comment: Please read the guidelines of [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question with examples and whatever usefull for the community to help you find a solution

Comment: This might help you https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/relevance-intro.html